# How to make a unit test for a C# DateTime related function timezone independent?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datetime, timezone

This unit test shall test a datetime string conversion method for an error, when parsing a (near) max value *9999-12-31T23:59:59Z*, in a timezone positive from UTC, e.g. Central European Time (+01:00 in winter). My goal is to reproduce the original error, without the fix, in a UTC or negative timezone (e.g. America)

The method used the standard C# *DateTime.Parse(datetimeString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)*,
which parsed the time into a local time, even with the Z timezone qualifier, shifting the value beyond the valid max into the year 10000, causing an out-of-range exception. The error itself could be fixed by adding a parameter *DateTimeStyle.AdjustToUniversal* to the parse function. But in a UTC or negative timezone, it would have never occurred, unless somebody ran the application where it's shifted out.

How can I test the function in a meaningful way, without changing the system configuration to another timezone, if the unit test runs on a system with UTC time or negative timezone?

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyApplicationConversions_MaxValue_LocalOutOfRange()
{
    // last second, without fractional seconds.
    const string maxValueUtc = "9999-12-31T23:59:59Z"; 
    Assert.AreEqual(maxValueUtc, MyApplicationConversions.CreateApplicationUtcDateTime(maxValueUtc));
}
```

Comment: This is a guess but could you not write a piece of code that simulates the behavior of the different time zones? Take UTC as reference, and add respective offsets for the different time zones, and the conditions regarding time change in summer or winter? Then you run your test on all the time zones you have defined

Comment: Otherwise I think the only option is to change the system's time zone for every test. I am convinced you can do that from within a C# code

Comment: @snus74 - Unfortunately, there's not a good way to do that in a thread-safe manner.  Changing the time zone is a system-level operation on Windows, and at minimum a process-level operation in other operating systems.  Running multiple tests in parallel, or just trying to make sure changing the time zone didn't break *other* tests, would be near impossible.

Comment: indeed if you dont want a simulated behavior it is a sequential process. Perhaps only select critical tests to run under different time zones and run these sequentially?